# Which for loop is better/faster?

Tags: c++

Is there a difference between:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

and:

```
for (int i(0); i != n; ++i)
```

They seem to be virtually identical to me. Which one is better than the other?

Comment: The second one can easily lead to an infinite loop (negative `n`, or `i` being increased beyond `n` in the body.)

Comment: Regarding performance you can hardly notice a difference between these two.

Comment: This loop is faster: `while (false);`.

Comment: I like the second one better, tastes like strawberry.

Comment: If you want to check for differences, look at the compiled assembly code.

Comment: I think they are pretty much as good as each other. As for the second one being less safe, I'm not sure I agree. If `i` is being improperly modified within the body of the loop you have a serious problem regardless. At least an infinite loop is easy to detect as a symptom.

Comment: @Galik And if `n` is negative? It won't be an infinite loop, but it will be quite long.

Comment: @juanchopanza Same argument, `n` should not be negative if `i` is expected to become equal to it and an infinite loop may be much easier to detect than a silently working bad loop.

Comment: @Galik It would be a silently working bad loop.

Comment: If `n` is negative, the undefined behavior sanitizer will catch it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes you are right. But then the answer depends on what you intend the loop to achieve, in which case the *best* is the one that isn't a bug. I was assuming both loops had the same goal in mind that didn't involve accepting a negative value as an intended early termination. I could construct use case where literally `i != n` is always right for -ve and +ve values of `n` but `i < n` is always wrong.

Comment: @Galik I would like to see that.

Comment: The point is we are making *assumptions* about the intended use here and I believe for the most obvious use case (iterating between 0 and some +ve number) there is a potential bug that neither can avoid and is equally destructive.

Answer (score 2):

The second will fail if `n` is negative; `i < n` is a safer termination condition.

Apart from that, there's no difference for simple types like `int`.

For more complicated types, one might prefer the direct initialisation and pre-increment of the second. The first, at least in principle, might require a copy during initialisation and each increment, although in many cases these can be optimised out.

Comment: The issue with `n` being negative is probably less important than the issue if you're not always advancing `i` by exactly one; if you might increment it in the loop, or if you're doing `i += step`, instead of `++ i` in the increment.  (The other issue is that you must do `i != n` with iterators, so if you want to be coherent...)

Answer (score 1):

There is nearly no difference. I compiled a demo software with g++.
Here is the assembly for `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`:

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $10, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
.L2:
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    jl  .L3    ;------ if compiled with other for loop there is "jne   .L3"
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I commented the line that is different if you compile it with `for(int i(0); i != n; ++i)`. As you can see the only difference is that in one case the compare operation is jump if less and in the other case there is jump if not equal.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to talk about speed, since the two do
different things.  Generally, however:

- For historical reasons, *all* of the code I've seen uses copy
  initialization in the *for-init-statment* (to the point where
  I wan't sure that the second was even legal).  In practice,
  unless you have a very, very bad compiler, and a horribly
  complicated iterator, it shouldn't make a difference.  Just use
  which ever the local coding standards say, and don't worry about
  it.
- Historically, the `i < n` has been preferred, on the grounds
  that it works even if you happen to increment `i` in the loop as
  well.  In C++, however, the `i != n` has become idiomatic, since
  it also works with iterators and pointers.  It has also been
  argued that if you do accidentally increment the index or
  iterator once too many in the loop, it's better to go off into
  nowhere land than for the program to seem to work.  Anyway, in
  modern C++, I'd recommend `i != n`, unless your local coding
  standard explicitly says otherwise, *of* the algorithm
  intentionally expects `i` to possibly go beyond `n` (e.g. you're
  using a stride, and the incrementation is `i += step`, where
  `step` isn't guaranteed to be a multiple of `n`).
- Despite claims to the contrary, there's no difference between
  `i++` and `++i` with any modern compiler and any reasonable
  iterator.  Because some authors have claimed that `++i` may be
  faster, however, it's become usual in C++.  If you have existing
  code using `i++`, or the local coding standard says to use it,
  use `i++`; otherwise, use `++i`, simply to avoid arguments with
  people who've read that it's faster.  (The authors claiming that
  it's faster never actually published a benchmark supporting
  their claim.)

The result is that:

```
for ( int i = 0; i != n; ++ i )
```

is probably the most idiomatic in C++ code, but in all cases,
you should follow the local coding standard and existing code
(if working on a legacy project).  And don't worry about the
relative speed of each; it almost certainly won't make
a difference.

Comment: did you mean `i!=n` instead of the two instances of `i==n` in your second bullet?

Answer (score 0):

Others already said that in practice, it makes no difference. I agree on that, because modern compilers simply optimize away the differences.

If you are talking about principle, though, there is a difference (three to be exact). Lets assume preconditions ensure that the two variants have the same effects.

1: `int i = 0` asks the compiler to create a variable, initialize it, and then set it to 0 (using its `operator =`). That initialization might, on theoretical platforms and compilers, include setting i to some defined value. `int i(0)` on the other hand tells the compiler to initialize the variable to 0, thus possibly saving the superfluous initialization.

2: This part is, in lack of precise knowledge, a bit vague. `i < n` requires, for many CPUs, the compiler to generate a subtraction, extract a sign bit, then conditionally jump on that. `i != n` on the other hand requires a subtraction, then jump on the 'is zero' bit.

3: `i++` asks the compiler to make a copy of `i` (that is returned and not used later), then increment it. `++i` on the other hand increments, then returns a reference to `i`.

In conclusion: In all three cases is the second variant in principle less work to do for the executing processor.